Back Gesture Navigation + back activity transitions on API <34 not working consistently
So it seems like on the documentation [0][1] all focus on Android 14+ and don't even mention how you should handle lower versions. I tried out a bit and thought this would work nicely:
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            overrideActivityTransition(AppCompatActivity.OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN, R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, 0)
            overrideActivityTransition(AppCompatActivity.OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_CLOSE, R.anim.stay, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom)
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.stay)
        }

//...

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    @Deprecated("")
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom)
        }
    }

//... 

    fun handleUiStuff() {
        onCloseButtonClick = { onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() }
    }

The result of this is:

For API 34+ it works great. Opening and closing transitions are consistent, the back gesture transition looks good.
For API 33 and below the opening transition is fine. The closing transition is fine when using the hardware back button. But when onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() is called in reaction to an UI component, the old onBackPressed is not called, so overridePendingTransition is not called and the transition is not custom.

I'm having a hard time understanding this, but I don't mind too much. I just want the transitions to be consistent. In this trivial case I could call overridePendingTransition inside handleUiStuff, but at other cases I would probably not want to do that, when also using a BackHandler and other stuff, I guess?
Video of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqRXUSfXt5M
[0] https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture
[1] https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/support-animations

You can't use Activity.onBackPressed and onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() together. If you want to use the new API, you have to exclusively use the new API.
You should replace this logic with a OnBackPressedCallback added to onBackPressedDispatcher via         getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
@Deprecated("")
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom)
    }
}
enter code here

with
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
        overrideActivityTransition(AppCompatActivity.OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN, R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, 0)
        overrideActivityTransition(AppCompatActivity.OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_CLOSE, R.anim.stay, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom)
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.stay)
    }
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        this,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
                    finish()
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom)
                }
            }
        },
    )
}

